# Ubuntu Server 16.04 Letsencrypt SSL Website Configuration File

Tags: server, 16.04, apache2, encryption, ssl

I am new to Linux. I have sucessfully set up a server with Linode, and have installed a LAMP stack and my website works now. What I wanted to do was install a SSL certificate using "Lets Encrypt". I followed the guide here https://www.linode.com/docs/security/ssl/install-lets-encrypt-to-create-ssl-certificates.

After that I got this message:
IMPORTANT NOTES:

- Congratulations! Your certificate and chain have been saved at /etc/letsencrypt/live/msystim.com/fullchain.pem. Your cert will expire on 2017-02-05. To obtain a new or tweaked version of this certificate in the future, simply run letsencrypt-auto again. To non-interactively renew *all* of your certificates, run "letsencrypt-auto renew"
- If you lose your account credentials, you can recover through e-mails sent to matthew.amescua@msystim.com.
- Your account credentials have been saved in your Certbot configuration directory at /etc/letsencrypt. You should make a secure backup of this folder now. This configuration directory will also contain certificates and private keys obtained by Certbot so making regular backups of this folder is ideal.

So that's all good.

Now what I was wondering is how to set up my site configuration file to use the certificate?

Current Set Config looks like this

[image]

Comment: Have a look here: [CertBot](https://certbot.eff.org/#ubuntuxenial-apache) - It's a much more efficient way of doing it, and it sets up your config for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a directive to your site config for ssl.  You'll need to modify the following to match your site settings.  Once you've made your changes, you'll need to `sudo service apache2 reload` for it to take affect.

---

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/example.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/example.com.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt  #If using a self-signed certificate, omit this line

    ServerAdmin info@example.com
    ServerName www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html/
    ErrorLog /var/www/example.com/log/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/example.com/log/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I got this error code when I tried that ........Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.     Does port 80 need to stay turned on? Do I need to change the apache config file? Is port 443 possibly not open?

Comment: The output from systemctl status will give more insight.  You don't need to keep port 80 on, though usually it's a good idea to redirect to 443.  I'm not sure if it actually checks if 443 is open, I'd imagine not.